# Use page-object gem to check a box in a table

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, pageobjects, page-object-gem

My page has a table with a checkbox in the first column. I want to check the box in each row up to a given number.
I can do this in watir-webdriver, but not with page-object; possibly due to the HTML structure.

HTML - edited for relevancy (there is more than one table in the page; note this table element has no identifying attributes):

```
<div id="other-students">
<div class="table-wrapper">
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input id="select-all" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-click="otherStudentsWidget.toggleAll(selectAll)" ng-model="selectAll">
    </th>
    <th>
      ...
    </th>
    <th>
      ...
    </th>
    <th>
      ...
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="ng-hide" ng-show="!studentsFetched || !otherStudents.length">
  <tr class="loading-row ng-hide" ng-show="!studentsFetched">
    <td colSpan="4">Loading students...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="loading-row" ng-show="studentsFetched">
     <td colSpan="4">No students</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody style="display: table-row-group;" class="ng-isolate-scope" student-widget="" students="otherStudents" show-highlighting="true" checked-students="checkedOtherStudents" api="otherStudentsWidget">
   <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="student-widget-0-13233" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="student-widget-0-13233">Test</label></td>
      <td>
        <label for="student-widget-0-13233">Student</label></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- rest of the table rows omitted for brevity -->
```

I can click the correct control using watir-webdriver:

```
@browser.div(:id => 'other-students').div(:class => 'table-wrapper').table[3][0].checkbox.set
```

My pageObject class (including numerous attempts of failing code, which have been commented out). I have tried to check the box directly, and by first finding the row in the table.

```
class EditGroupPage 
  include PageObject
  CHECKBOX_COL = 0
  div(:otherStudents, :id => 'other-students')
  #div(:studentList) {:otherStudents_element.div_element(:index => 1) }    #fails
  #div(:studentList) {:otherStudents_element.div(:index => 1) }  #fails
  #div(:studentList) {otherStudents_element.div(:index => 1) }  #fails
div(:studentList){otherStudents_element.div_element(:index => 1) }  #table-wrapper div
table(:students){studentList_element.table_element}  #doesn't quite fail, but has a warning that table can't be used like that.
#table(:students, studentList_element.table)   #fails
#divs(:allDivs) = otherStudents_element.div_elements
checkbox(:selectStudent){students_element[CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox_element}
checkbox(:chooseStudent, :id => /student-widget-0/)

def tickStudents(iNumberOfStudents)
    cCurrentRow = 0
    while cCurrentRow < iNumberOfStudents #Check the box for cCurrentRow
        #otherStudents.tableWrapper.table[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox_element.click     #fails
        #allDivs[1].div_element.table[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox_element.click  #fails 
        #studentList_element.table[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox_element.click  #fails
        #studentList_element.table[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox_element.click  #fails
        #studentList_element.table[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox.checkbox_element.click  #fails
        #studentList_element.table[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox.check_checkbox_element #fails
        #studentList_element.table[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox_element.click  #fails
        #studentList_element[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox_element.click  #fails
        #students[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox_element.click  #fails
    #   students[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox_element #fails
    #   students[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].check_checkbox_element      #fails
    #   students[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].check #fails
    #   students[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].click #fails
    #   students[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox.checkbox_element.click  #fails
        #students[cCurrentRow].checkbox_element.check  #fails
    #   students[cCurrentRow].element.checkbox.set  #fails
        #students[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox.click     #fails
#studentList_element.table[cCurrentRow][CHECKBOX_COL].checkbox.chooseStudent.click  #fails
        cCurrentRow += 1 #we should have checked the box in current row by now, so move on to next row
    end
end
```

I've made many attempts to get this working. How can I use page-object to check the box?

Comment: I can remove some of the HTML or unused code if it is confusing; I figured it was better to include all the context I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [plural](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/defining-element-collections-using-the-page-objects-gem/) version of your element name to get an array of matching elements. So define something generic enough to capture all your checkboxes, and then create a method to tick the correct number of them. I haven't tested this but I think it would look something like:

```
checkboxes(:student_widget, id: /student-widget/)

def tick_students(n)
  self.student_widget_elements.each_with_index do |cb, i|
    cb.check if i < n
  end
end
```

Comment: That was pretty much bang-on, except that it should be `cb.check` instead of `.set`

Comment: I updated the answer to fix that. Thanks for letting me know and glad I could help.

Comment: hi, I am new to this pageobject gem,  can this be used for WATIR? Because it throws the error for me when I use WATIR.    

ERROR : already initialized constant Watir::VERSION
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.7.0/lib/watir-webdriver/version.rb:2: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here

Comment: RAJ, page-object is intended for use with watir-webdriver, not watir. If my answer is not sufficient, try asking this as a new question, as your comment does not relate to the original question here.